# Tkinter TclError python ubuntu canopy

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, tkinter, canopy

I am using a program that works on Tkinter when I call the startup script everything works but when I tell it to plot a graph, I receive the error as :

```
>  Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File
> "/home/user/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.7.2.3327.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
> line 1536, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "/home/user/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.7.2.3327.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
> line 587, in callit
>     func(*args)   File "/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
> line 373, in idle_draw
>     self.draw()   File "/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
> line 355, in draw
>     tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)   File
> "/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 30, in blit
>     id(data), colormode, id(bbox_array)) TclError
```

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, python 2.7.11, Canopy 1.7.2 and I tried to change the PyLab backend to SVG from Qt4 on Canopy Preferences but nothing changed. Also since the program is trying to do some plots and I guess because of the Tkinter I also receive the error from the program as:

```
   RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/snpy in <module>()
----> 1 s.fit()

/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snpy/sn.pyc in fit(self, bands, mangle, kcorr, reset_kcorrs, k_stretch, margs, **args)
   1291             self.model.fit(bands, **args)
   1292       if self.replot:
-> 1293          self.plot()
   1294 
   1295    def fitMCMC(self, bands=None, Nwalkers=None, threads=1, Niter=500, 

/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snpy/sn.pyc in plot(self, **kwargs)
   1615       '''
   1616 
-> 1617       return plotmod.plot_sn(self, **kwargs)
   1618 
   1619    def plot_kcorrs(self, colors=None, symbols=None, outfile=None):

/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snpy/plot_sne_mpl.pyc in plot_sn(self, **kwargs)
    695    #p.draw()
    696    p.set_limits(dox=(xrange is None), doy=(yrange is None), all_equal=1)
--> 697    p.draw()
    698    outfile = kwargs.get('outfile', None)
    699    if outfile is not None:

/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snpy/myplotlib.pyc in draw(self, hide_corner_labels)
    945       #3) Make room for everything:
    946       if self._title is not None:
--> 947          title_height = self.get_bbox(self._title).height
    948       else:
    949          title_height = 0

/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snpy/myplotlib.pyc in get_bbox(self, label)
    738    def get_bbox(self, label):
    739       '''If a title exists, how tall is it?'''
--> 740       bbox = label.get_window_extent()
    741       bboxi = bbox.inverse_transformed(self.fig.transFigure)
    742       return bboxi

/home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    957             self._renderer = renderer
    958         if self._renderer is None:
--> 959             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
    960 
    961         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer
```

Even though all these errors, when I told it to plot a graph, it shows me an empty page with a save option and when I save I can see it later by opening that saved file however the plot is so messed up because of the render issue etc. Are there any suggestions about how to deal with this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example which produces this error.